# How to Bloat embedded youtube video frame on website when I click on play?

Tags: css, html, youtube, web

I have embedded youtube videos on my website(HTML5 and CSS). I have 3 videos which shows up next to each other to fit in the margin of the website. But when I click on play, the frame doesn't expand and hence plays in the same frame but that is too small for viewers.

Expectation: Its ok to have it in small frame in website but when the user clicks on "Play" button, the frame must expand to say 1100 * 450 and go back to fit in its small frame when its done or when the user clicks elsewhere in the page.
I don't want to use the "Full screen" option since that covers the entire webpage.

Any ideas how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a popup for that. Have a image of the video, then when some one clicks on it the video pops up and plays

Comment: Do you have a code or something explaining how to use popup? All I get is for use with wordpress themes. I didn't use wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

hey buddy replace your iframe code with this one

fullscreen is the only option,
scalable iframe is something different,
i hope u find it useful.

```
<iframe height="400" width="600" name="frame" id="iframe" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```